# find the image and preimage of complex mappings

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I am new to complex analysis and am having hard time visualizing the image and preimage of some complex functions that i encountered while self preparing for this course. I have a map $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by $f$$_n$($z$) = $z$$^n$ for various $n$.
now my first thought  was to write $z$ in its polar form but that didnt get me any further because i never used polar expressions, second that doesn't help me to describe the mapping geometrically
Any hints or explanations are appreciated, even references to websites where where I can learn more about complex mappings are welcomed.

Comment: You need to understand more about complex arithmetic, specifically how multiplication works using polar coordinates (the executive summary is that you multiply the moduli and add the arguments, geometrically that means $z \mapsto z^n$  combines the function $x \mapsto x^n$ for $x$ on the real axis with a function that winds the unit circle $n$ times around itself ). For an online reference, you could start with the Wikipedia page on [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane).

Comment: $n$ is an integer?  The mapping $z \to z^2$ squares the magnitude of $z$, and doubles its argument.  Best seen with polar coordinates.  $z=re^{i\theta}$.  Then $z^2=r^2 e^{i2\theta}$.

Comment: @mjw n is various, it could be positive integer or negative. I have chosen to write complex number in exponential form in studying image of this complex mapping. So looking at what you have done, i have started substituting from $n$ = 3 so $z^3$= $r^3$ $e^i*6.θ$, that's right ?

Comment: $z^3=r^3 e^{i3\theta}.$

Comment: $f_n(z) = z^n = r^n e^{i n \theta}.$

Comment: Do you have a region (a wedge or sector of an annulus, for example) and a particular mapping (a particular value of $n$)?  One 'technique' is to map the boundary, and then show that the interior maps to the interior of the image.

Comment: @mjw Not really, It doesn't give a particular region or a value for n. But i can work on a disk for easiness and take values 1,-1, $i$, $-i$, how would that be? it does form a rotation, but how would i describe the preimage using the exponential form, not the complex form $a$+$b$$i$?

Comment: If your initial point(s) are on the unit circle, then under the mapping $f=z^n$, the image of these points will be on the unit circle.  That is because $r=1$ and $r^n=1.$

Comment: $\left\{ 1,-1,i,-i \right\}=\left\{  e^0, e^{i \pi}, e^{i \pi/2},e^{-i \pi /2} \right\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few examples:

Let $Q$ be the quarter circle of radius 2 and its interior in the upper right half plane:

$$Q=re^{i\theta}, \quad 0\le r \le 2, 0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2 }$$

The image of $Q$ under the mapping $f_2(z) = z^2$ is the semicircle of radius $4$ in the upper half plane and its interior.

$$f_2(Q)=re^{i\theta}, \quad 0\le r \le 4,\,\, 0\le \theta \le 
\pi$$

The image of $Q$ under the mapping $f_3(z)=z^3$ is the union of three quarter circles, of radius $8$, and its "interior" spanning the first three quadrants.

$$f_3(Q)=re^{i\theta}, \quad 0\le r \le 8,\,\, 0\le \theta \le \frac{3\pi}{2 }$$

The image of $Q$ under the mapping $f_{-1}(z)=z^{-1}$ is the quarter circle, of radius $\frac{1}{2}$, and its "exterior" in the fourth quadrant.

$$f_{-1}(Q)=re^{i\theta}, \quad  r \ge \frac{1}{2}, \,\, 0\ge \theta \ge -\frac{\pi}{2 }$$

Comment: That really makes it easier to visualize, thanks! And the preimage would just be the n-root of the points in the image set but again how would you describe the preimage?

Comment: In all three examples, $Q$ is the preimage.  The images under various mappings are $f_2(Q), f_3(Q), f_{-1}(Q).$